# How do i update this textarea plugin with .live()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, textarea

i've been working on this for more than hours and hours and i cant figure it out. I've downloaded this textarea expansion plug in over here  http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/ and it works. But i am creating a dynamic page that adds textareas after the document is ready and i cant find a way to modify the plug-in so that it will apply to future textareas. I am fairly new to jQuery but i really need help. Thank you so much!

Also, on a sidenote, i had some trouble with the textareas themselves. How do i make it so that the textarea is able to interpret line breaks when the user hits enter/return. So far it just parses out the text as a single string with no breaks. For jQuery, i was basically taking the value of the textboxt with .val() and placing on a paragraph somewhere. That paragraph happens to be only a single line with no line breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: You can really only use `.live()` on DOM events (click, mousedown, form submit, etc.). Rather than worrying about modifying the plugin, why not simply run the plugin on the newly created textareas immediately after creation?

Comment: I see what you mean now. That makes sense. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this...

http://jsfiddle.net/QrKuF/1/

Matt is correct.

Comment: I see why this work, every time the user clicks , the function gets to executed and applied for any existing textareas. Needed an example to understand it so thanks!

Comment: @Ben You're welcome. Please show your thanks by accepting correct answers and/or upvoting other helpful answers. `/\n/g` is a regular expression. `/` denotes the beginning of the expression and the second `/` denotes the end of the expression. In between the `/`'s is the text or character to be matched against. `/\n/g` Is going to match the `\n` or newline character. The `g` at the end is a regular expression modifier. This `g` is telling the expression to match ALL `\n`'s nstead of just the first.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, it's because textarea stores new line character but html wont understand it. If you want to set new lines in your div, you can replace the new line characters with br tag.

example here
http://jsfiddle.net/jkhnV/2/

Comment: you need the global modifier to replace all `\n`'s http://jsfiddle.net/jkhnV/1/ - `/\n/g`

Comment: Perfect!!! This is exactly what i am looking  for. If anyone has a bit of extra time, i thought new line characters were /n, so why wont you just put .replace (/n, "<br />"). What is the \ and /g for? Thanks so much for the help though!

Comment: It solved it, but i was just wanted to know what the /g is for.